# Convert dictionary keys into rows and values into columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
info = {'GENE_X': {'AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG-1': 3,
                   'AAACCCAGTATACCTG-1': 1,
                   'AAACCCAGTCGTACTA-1': 6},
        'GENE_Y': {'AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG-1': 2,
                   'AAACCCAGTATACCTG-1': 0,
                   'AAACCCAGTCGTACTA-1': 0}
}
```

I want a file outputted such that the keys become the rows and the second set of keys become the columns, like so:

```
        AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG-1  AAACCCAGTATACCTG-1  AAACCCAGTCGTACTA-1
GENE_X  3                   1                   6
GENE_Y  2                   0                   0
```

How can I achieve this with pandas? I've set it up like the following so far, but am not sure how to sort out the other arguments:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([what goes here?], columns=list(value.keys() for key, value in info.iteritems()))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a dataframe from the existing dictionary and transpose:

```
pd.DataFrame(info).T
```

or `from_dict` with `orient='index'`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(info,orient='index')
```

---

```
        AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG-1  AAACCCAGTATACCTG-1  AAACCCAGTCGTACTA-1
GENE_X                   3                   1                   6
GENE_Y                   2                   0                   0
```